# Tool to convert SEC EDGAR Form 13F into Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I'm using Windows 10.
I'm looking for a tool to convert `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1037389/000103738919000272/xslForm13F_X01/renaissance13Fq32019_holding.xml` to `.xls`.

I found [Intrinio](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-SEC-filings-so-ugly-to-read) on Quora, but prefer free solution. Note that Andrew Carpenter (who made that post) is a COO there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been downloading [these free data sets](https://sites.google.com/view/sec-form-13f-data-sets/) of Form 13F data converted into .xlsx. You can just download the .xlsx and start analzying. It looks like you're interested in Renaissance. So you can just download the relevant quarter of .xlsx data and look at the list of Renaissance holdings.